# What is the <jdoc:include>? Is it HTML or PHP?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

`< jdoc:include >`

But I do not know how the above works. I mean, how is it compiled?

How does the HTML Code recognize that this is related to Joomla!

Answer (score 0):

It is Joomla syntax. `<jdoc ...` is processed by the Joomla engine to output specific information. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements).

The "HTML code" really has nothing to do with it, it is compiled by Joomla before serving the page to the browser.

Comment: thanks. so how can i make my own syntax ? do u have any for learning it?

Comment: There are tons of resources for learning Joomla, both how to use the CMS and how to program using the framework. I suggest that you spend some time investigating them and then post questions on [joomla.se].